# multiple if statements in Swift

Tags: swift, if-statement

```
@IBAction func addtoCart(_ sender: Any) {
    if UserDataSingleton.sharedDataContainer.is_guest == "guest"  {
        //segue, user is a guest 
    }

    if sizebtn.isHidden == false {
        if Size.selectedItem == nil {
            // show alert , nothing is selected from items
        }
    } else {
        // do API call
    } 
}
```

The code above skips api calls if the user is not a guest and has selected something from item. How can I check if :

1. user is not a guest
2. if UIButton isn't hidden and user has selected from item

Answer (score 1):

You can use "&&" logic operator to do second statement

```
@IBAction func addtoCart(_ sender: Any) {

   if  UserDataSingleton.sharedDataContainer.is_guest == "guest"  {
      //segue, user is a guest 
      return
   }


   if (sizebtn.isHidden == false) && (Size.selectedItem != nil) {
      // do API call , SOMETHING is selected from items
   } else {
      //show alert nothing is selected
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `guard` statement to do validations:

```
@IBAction func addtoCart(_ sender: Any) {
   guard UserDataSingleton.sharedDataContainer.is_guest != "guest" else {
       //segue, user is a guest
       return 
   }

   guard sizebtn.isHidden && Size.selectedItem == nil else {
       // show alert , nothing is selected from items
       return
   }

    // do API call  
}
```

Comment: always segues even if is_guest != "guest"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your if statements were not bundled right. Try this

```
@IBAction func addtoCart(_ sender: Any) {

    if  UserDataSingleton.sharedDataContainer.is_guest == "guest"  {

       //segue, user is a guest 
    }

    if sizebtn.isHidden == false {
        if Size.selectedItem == nil {
            // show alert , nothing is selected from items
        } else {
            // do API call
        } 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func addtoCart(_ sender: Any) {

    if  UserDataSingleton.sharedDataContainer.is_guest == "guest"  {
       //segue, user is a guest
       return 
    }

    if sizebtn.isHidden == false && Size.selectedItem == nil {
       // show alert , nothing is selected from items
       return
    }

    // do API call  
 }
```

Use `return` when to don't want to execute your code further.